# Component functions of the exterior derivative

Tags: exterior-algebra, lie-derivative, exterior-derivative

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $(E_i)$ a smooth local frame for $M$, and ($\varepsilon^i$) the dual coframe. For each $i$, let $b^{i}_{jk}$ denote the component functions of the exterior derivative of ($\varepsilon^i$), i.e, $$d\varepsilon^i = \sum_{j<k} b^{i}_{jk} \varepsilon^{j} \wedge \varepsilon^{k},$$ and for each $j$, $k$, let $c^{i}_{jk}$ be the component functions of the Lie bracket $[E_j, E_k]$, i.e, $$[E_j, E_k] = c^{i}_{jk}E_i.$$ I wanna to prove that $b^{i}_{jk} = -c^{i}_{jk}$.

Using the formula $d\omega(X, Y) = X(\omega(Y)) - Y(\omega(X)) - \omega([X, Y])$, I know that $$d \varepsilon^{i}(E_u, E_v) = - \varepsilon^{i}([E_u, E_v]) = - c^{i}_{uv},$$ but I can't see how to finish. How to prove that, on the other hand, $d\varepsilon^{i}(E_u, E_v) = \displaystyle\sum_{j<k} b^{i}_{jk} \varepsilon^{j} \wedge \varepsilon^{k}(E_u, E_v) = b^{i}_{uv}?$

Comment: There is nothing to prove! This is simply by definition. The two-form $\varepsilon^j \wedge \varepsilon^k$ has the property that if you plug in any pair OTHER THAN $E_j$ and $E_k$, you get $0$, and $\varepsilon^j \wedge \varepsilon^k(E_j,E_k) = 1$.

Comment: Then $\sum_{j < k} b^{i}_{jk} \varepsilon^{j} \wedge \varepsilon^{k}(E_j, E_k) = \sum_{j < k} b^{i}_{jk} = b^{i}_{jk}$? I do not understand this

Comment: It kind of doesn't make sense to plug in $E_j$ and $E_k$ and also have $j$ and $k$ be the indices that are summed over. On the one hand, plugging in $E_j$ and $E_k$ make it seem like $j$ and $k$ are constant. On the other hand, having $j < k$ under the sum makes it seem like you sum over ALL combinations of $j$ and $k$. It can't be both, so which is it?

Comment: Edited. See again, please.

Comment: Ohh now I got to see the solution. Thank you very much @Nick!! You saved me.